# Trouble with connecting jupyter notebook remote server on windows 10

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I tried all the instructions noted on the internet
I use windows 10 Education for the server system and I would like to connect with windows 10 Education laptop.
However it keep shows ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on the screen.
I use chrome to access. 
Below is what I did to connect:
anaconda, jupyter is up to date.

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config

c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.password_required = True
c.NotebookApp.port = 9000
c.NotebookApp.password = u'hashed pw'
```

I opend inbound rule and opened the port(9000)

and then

```
jupyter notebook --ip=[my ipv4 address] --port=9000
```

and it shows
The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 20:48:18.585 NotebookApp] http://my ipv4 address:9000/

I can access on my desktop or mobile phone using same internet that the server uses, but I can't access with other internet line.

Comment: Please tag sensibly.